# How to read bytes at an address in C?

Tags: c, memory

I am working with some page table entries and have a virtual address. Each page has data on it and the virtual address is mapped to that page.

If I have a 32 bit virtual address, how can I "grab" the first byte at a specific virtual address?

```
int *virtualAddress = someaddress;
int byteAtAddress = *(virtualAddress);
int secondByte = *(virtualAddress + 4);
```

Obviously I am getting 4 bytes instead of getting one byte. What trick can I use here to only get one byte?

Comment: You do know about casting? You could try to cast the pointer.

Comment: `char *virtualAddress = someaddress;` will do.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: unsigned char*, strictly speaking.

Comment: @Bathsheba You are right, I actually just fixed my answer.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Thank you, have an upvote.

Comment: Read the `int` (better use an `uint32_t` if you mean byte == 8 bits) and shift/mask each octet.

Comment: What is "the first byte"? The byte stored at the lowest address, the least significant byte of an integer, or the most significant byte of an integer?

Answer (score 4):

The C standard permits you to *cast* an address of memory that you own to an `unsigned char*`:

`unsigned char* p = (unsigned_char*)someaddress;`

You can then extract the memory one byte at a time using pointer arithmetic on `p`. Be careful not to go beyond the memory that you own - bear in mind that and int could be as small as 16 bits.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` could be as low as `1`. And this method does nto account for endianess or encoding. Better use shift/masks on the original `int` (way better: use an `uint32_t`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you ask, but still is apparently a valid question. I say "*I don't understand*", because you say "*Obviously I am getting 4 bytes*"

```
unsigned char *virtualAddress = comeaddress;
unsigned char byteAtAddress = virtualAddress[0];
```

Note, that pointer arithmetic takes consideration of the pointer type so `*(virtualAddress + 4)` is<sup>1</sup> actually adding 16 bytes to the base address.

In fact it is equivalent to

```
*((unsigned char *) virtualAddress + 4 * sizeof(*virtualAddress))
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Assuming you are on a regular system where `sizeof(int) == 4` whichs is not necessarily true.</sub>

Comment: The answer asumes `sizeof(int) == 4`. This is not guaranteed by the standard. It could be as low as `1`.